# Is this online shop legit?

Tags: lego-store

I am wondering if this site is legit or no because I want to buy this LEGO set.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

You can see the URL in the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a scam. I was going to write reasons why it is so, but there are so much red flags all over this website, I don't know where to begin.. Even Chinese copy cost more.

Comment: thanks a lot you saved me 50 euro

Comment: Just look at the "reviews". Half of them aren't even about this set. Parts of the web-page are rip-offs of the official Lego site or link through to the original Lego sources. This has all the hallmarks of a rip-off site and the prices are just too good to be true.